# I am not able to compile a simple program using gcc

Tags: apt, 64-bit, compiling, gcc, g++

Wrongly I have install ia32-libs but my host system is 64 bit.
Now whenever i try to compile c file i get a message

```
as: unrecognized option '--64'
```

I have uninstall th ia32-libs but I am getting same error.
then I have uninstall the  gcc,g++,multilib and build-essenstial  using purge command.
again install these packages using apt-get command but again same error. When i run "which gcc" command on terminal i get "/usr/bin/gcc " and "which ld" output is "/usr/bin/ld".
I guess both outputs are correct.

When i run this command

```
g++ -v hello hello.c
```

then output is

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.6 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-plugin --enable-objc-gc --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -D_GNU_SOURCE he.c -quiet -dumpbase he.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase he -version -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccIQSmoy.s
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
include "..." search starts here:
include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/4.6
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/.
 /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) version 4.6.3 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.3, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.1.0-p3, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 65b5171ac1bd7b3f07dbea6bdb24be3d
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as --64 -o /tmp/ccXDnoi3.o /tmp/ccIQSmoy.s
**as: unrecognized option '--64'**
```

Can you tell me how to solve this problem??

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `which as` and `as --version` as well please. Also your OS version (I'm guessing 12.04 based on the gcc version?)

Comment: which as output:
"/usr/bin/as"      
as --version output:                               
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22
Copyright 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-linux-gnueabi'.

why target is pointing towards my cross compiler??
 if this is a error how to correct it??
and, yes, OS is 12.04.

Comment: You could try to re install 'as' on your system with 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils'

Comment: __Please edit your question to add the new information__. Yes somehow the arm-linux-gnueabi version of `as` has got installed as the default `/usr/bin/as`. How to fix it will depend why that occurred - if you don't actually use/need the ARM toolchain you could simply re-install the `binutils` package, which _should_ overwrite it with the regular version. Otherwise you will need to do some more investigating - starting with whether `/usr/bin/as` is a simple file or a symbolic link.

Comment: Thnx..... By reinstalling binutils my problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The options for gcc is '-m32' or '-m64' to generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment. Not '--64'

Comment: How can i solve my problem?

Comment: i am not running --64 or -m64 as an option.

Comment: You probably have set it somewhere in your environmet. Check that with `printenv | grep "\-\-64"`

Comment: i got nothing on terminal when i run your command.
I run printenv command and check all environments.
--64 is not written anywhere.

Comment: There is a problem with my assembler. By re-installing binutils my problem is SOlved

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with my assembler.

When I run `as --version`

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22 Copyright 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc. 
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of the GNU General Public License version 3 or later. 
This program has absolutely no warranty. This assembler was configured for a target of `arm-linux-gnueabi'.
```

My assembler target is mistakenly pointing towards the `arm-linux-gnueabi` (which was a cross compiler in my case). So, by re-installing `binutils` my problem was solved.

Comment: remove all of paths containing the key word `arm` from the environment variable `$PATH` works for me too

Answer (score 0):

A similar phenomenon had occurred and was solved.

1. Built and installed gcc-4.9.2
2. Built another software. No problem.
3. Built and installed binutils-2.25
4. gcc failed with ..../bin/as: unrecognized option: `-xarch=generic'
5. Renamed /usr/local/i386-pc-solaris2.11/ with different name, which was installed by binutils including bin/as
6. gcc succeeded

This is my guess. Historically, gcc used an external assembler, as, which was 
included in binutils. Several years ago, gcc changed its implementation to have  functionality of 'as' in gcc itself. The time past. Even so, if gcc finds 'as' 
in the certain directories, gcc will use it, in place of internal 'as' functionality.